# Buefy select v-model does not store key but the value

Tags: vue.js, select, vuejs2, buefy

I have a Buefy select which looks like this

```
<b-select v-if="roles" v-model="invitationRole" :placeholder="$t('company.users.invitation.roles-placeholder')">
    <option v-for="(value, key) in roles"
        :key="key"
        :value="value">
        {{ value }}
    </option>
</b-select>
```

The role model looks like `[{'user': 'User'}, {'admin': 'Admin'}]`

The problem is that the the invitationRole variable which should contain currently selected option contains the value not the key. It means that it contains Admin not admin, or User not user.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong variable in the wrong place. If you want the "key" to be the "value" in the v-model when selected, then you need to use :value="key".

```
<b-select v-if="roles" v-model="invitationRole" :placeholder="$t('company.users.invitation.roles-placeholder')">
    <option v-for="(value, key) in roles"
        :value="key">
        {{ value }}
    </option>
</b-select>
```

To make more sense of this, try this:

```
<b-select v-if="roles" v-model="invitationRole" :placeholder="$t('company.users.invitation.roles-placeholder')">
    <option v-for="(roleName, roleKey) in roles"
        :value="roleKey">
        {{ roleName }}
    </option>
</b-select>
```